# How do apps actually receive the notifications?

Tags: android, ios, notifications, messaging

I have a very simple question. I have implemented push notifications many many times in apps, specially Android. But I am still curious to know, that how do these notifications library like, OneSignal or FCM actually check, if there is a new notification ?

What I think - 
They might be using some kind of listeners and checking for a new notification after a certain interval of time.

I would really love to read your answer...

Comment: Simply put - They use a socket (an always open connection) between the device and the cloud messaging service. You should read about sockets to understand more. Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19132186/4255978

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If simplified:

Android System (Google Play Services) establishes a socket connection to FCM server. This connection is kept alive *always*.
Once there is some message on the FCM server, it writes it's details to the socket. The data is transmitted to the device, and Google Play Services receive this data.
After that Google Play Services sends the data to the target application, who's FCM service is called and the notification data is passed to.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer Vladyslav Matviienko. Thanks a lot for your help...